# substitue string by index without using regular expressions

Tags: string, python-3.x, replace

It should be very easy, but I am looking for an efficient way to perform it.

I know that I could split the string into two parts and insert the new value, but I have tried to substitute each line between the indexes 22-26 as follows:

`line.replace(line[22:26],new_value)`

**The Problem**

However, that function substitutes everything in the line that is similar to the pattern in `line[22:26]`.

In the example below, I want to replace the marked number **1** with number **17**:

[image]

Here are the results. Note the replacement of `1` with `17` in several places:

[image]

Thus I don't understand the behavior of `replace` command. Is there a simple explanation of what I'm doing wrong?

**Why I don't want RE**

The values between index 22-26 are **not** unified in form.

*Note:* I am using python 3.5 on Unix/Linux machines.

Comment: `line[22:26]` gives you a string with `1` and some spaces. You use this pattern to replace every occurences in this line by `new_value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.replace` replaces 1 sub-string pattern with another everywhere in the string.

e.g.

```
'ab cd ab ab'.replace('ab', 'xy')
# produces output 'xy cd xy xy'
```

similarly,

```
mystr = 'ab cd ab ab'
mystr.replace(mystr[0:2], 'xy')
# also produces output 'xy cd xy xy'
```

what you could do instead, to replace *just* the characters in position 22-26

```
line = line[0:22] + new_value + line[26:]
```

Also, looking at your data, it seems to me to be a fixed-width text file. While my suggestion will work, a more robust way to process this data would be to read it & separate the different fields in the record first, before processing the data.

If you have access to the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library, it provides a useful function just for reading [fixed-width files](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html)